# Riddle: the deaths of atoms and a banker's wealth

Tags: riddle

> Let me tell you about myself, 
> about the deaths of atoms, 
> and a banker's wealth. 
> I can be bigger than the Earth, 
> or if you demand, 
> I can be smaller than a grain of sand. 
> I will even spin in circles if you know how to ask, 
> Which will help you greatly 
> with your wave-based tasks 
> If you look at how I change then you'll just find me. 
> I stay the same when you watch how I move, you see.

What am I?

Comment: I jumped straight to [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), so thanks for that. 

Comment: @Taco タコス Thanks for the formatting fix. Schrodinger's cat isn't the answer, though. The last two lines aren't referring to quantum measurement, since particles can still move while they are being measured.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't saying it was; I was just saying it made me *think* of Schrödinger's cat before anything else. Also, no problem! ‍♀️

Comment: Euler going to have to give us more hints, I think. My interest in this question is being compounded. In fact, I would say this question is a little more than 2.7 times more interesting reading it through again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> the exponential function e^x?

> Let me tell you about myself,
> about the deaths of atoms,
> and a banker's wealth.

> The amount of a material that undergoes radioactive decay follows an exponential curve over time, and so does interest on loans (just that one of the two decreases while the other increases).

> I can be bigger than the Earth,
> or if you demand,
> I can be smaller than a grain of sand.

> This one's not 100% clear to me, but exponential growth and decay can occur at any scale.

> I will even spin in circles if you know how to ask,

> Applying e^x to the imaginary numbers (specifically ones with an identical real component) results in a graph that looks exactly like a circle.

> Which will help you greatly
> with your wave-based tasks

> Fourier series and the Fourier transform (both used in many calculations involving waves) can both be written using the exponential function on imaginary numbers.

> If you look at how I change then you'll just find me.
> I stay the same when you watch how I move, you see.

> The derivative (which measures the rate of change of a function at any point, i.e. "you watch how I move") of e^x happens to be itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be:

> e (Euler's number).

Banker's wealth?

> e is used to calculate compound interest, the key to a banker's wealth.

Death of atoms?

> e comes up in the formula for radioactive decay, the death of atoms.

If you look at how I change then you'll just find me.
I stay the same when you watch how I move, you see?

> the first derivative of e is e itself.

I will even spin in circles if you know how to ask, which will help you greatly with your wave-based tasks?

> the curve e to the i phi = cos phi + i sin phi is a circle, and the discrete Fourier transform uses e

I can be bigger than the Earth, or if you demand, I can be smaller than a grain of sand?

> the digits of e are infinite, but "e" the symbol can be written very compactly

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more about why you think this is the answer? How does it refer to each line in the riddle?

Comment: ok, added more details